# $M= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$,find a rank one $2 \times 3$ matrix $N$ such that $\|M-N\|_2$ is minimized

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

We have a matrix $M= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$. My question is how to find a rank one $2 \times 3$ matrix $N$ such that $\|M-N\|_2$ is minimized?

I don't know where to start. I appreciate any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $$M=\sum_{i=1}^2\sigma_i U_i V_i^T$$ be the SVD decomposition where $\sigma_1 > \sigma_2$.

It is known that the best rank $1$ $2-$norm approximation is $M_1=\sigma_1U_1V_1^T$.

Similar result is known for best rank $k$ $2-$norm approximation or Frobenius norm approximation.